# Структура базы данных авторизации через соц. сети и сайт

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, авторизация, структуры-данных, логин

Как лучше создать структуру базы данных, если на сайте будет возможность зарегистрироваться и войти через сайт(стандартная форма входа и регистрации) и через соц. сети?

Если пользователь под одним email зарегистрировался на сайте затем вышел из учетной записи. У него есть аккаунт в соц. сети с регистрацией через этот-же email. Теперь, если пользователь произвел вход на сайт с этого аккаунта соц. сети, то .... он попадает в тот свой аккаунт, что создал ранее (email же один и тот же) или это уже другой аккаунт?

Если я правильно понял, то на примере  stackoverflow можно сделать единый аккаунт, который привязывается к email?

Тогда структура бд будет такой.

```
accaunts
---------
id
email

usersSite
---------
id
password
idAccaunt //внешний ключ accaunts.id

userFaceBook
------------
id
password
idAccaunt //внешний ключ accaunts.id
```

и т.п.

Правильно ли будет развивать такую структуру?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал идти немного другим путем.

У вас есть свой пользователь [user], а попасть в него - авторизироваться под ним - можно разными путями. Списком путей будут все варианты авторизации у вас на сайте, и он может пополняться, например

1. Прямая авторизация на сайте через почту/телефон и пароль
2. VK
3. OK
4. Google
5. Yandex
6. ...
7. StackEchange

При этом когда человек входит на ваш сайт, у него есть выбор:

1. Ввести почту и пароль -ИЛИ- ввести телефон и пароль (смотря как у вас принято)
2. Воспользоваться сторонней авторизацией на других сайтах - и список принятых у вас авторизаций

Пользователь выбирает удобный для себя способ, вы знаете этот выбор, и проверяете его вход по набору источников авторизации из первого списка. Все источники фактически будут отличаться только способом авторизации, реализацией в коде и URL для запроса авторизации. По сути результат авторизации может иметь три исхода:

1. Успешная. Почта/пароль подходят, ответ от сайта внешней авторизации успешен и так далее, пользователь найден. Все понятно, авторизируем
2. Не успешная. Почта/пароль не подходят, ответ от сайта авторизации отрицательный, все плохо. Что делать тоже понятно - введите пароль еще раз или восстановление пароля
3. Успешный, но не до конца. Ответ от сайта авторизации успешный, но у вас нет пользователя, связанного с таким аккаунтом. Здесь тоже все понятно, автоматически создаем у себя пользователя с таким источником авторизации и даем ему вход

Структура базы в данном случае довольно проста:

Таблица пользователей:

- [user_id] - уникальный внутренний ID пользователя у вас на сайте, у каждого пользователя свой
- [fields...] - любые поля, которые характерны именно для этого пользователя. Для одного.

Таблица источников авторизации:

- [user_id] - уникальный ID пользователя, к которому ведет этот источник авторизации
- [type] - тип авторизации, один из поддерживаемых на вашем сайта
- [fields...] - любые поля, которые характерны для вход именно этого пользователя именно с этого источника авториазции

Таблица текущих произведенных авторизаций:

- [user_id] - уникальный ID пользователя, для которого произведена авторизация
- [expire] - метка окончания авторизации, может быть либо 0/1, либо метка времени, либо вообще может не быть (вы можете просто удалять авторизацию при ее окончании, если вам не надо знать, кто когда через что заходил)
- [cookies] - некое поле или поля, которые содержат уникальный ключ/токен или что-то еще, что точно идентифицирует именно этот единичный вход пользователя. Это может быть кука браузера, которую отдали пользователю при авторизации через почту/пароль, или токен авторизации через VK
- [stats] - любые поля, описывающие именно этот вход пользователя, для статистики или безопасности. Сюда можно записывать браузер, машину, клиента, IP-адрес, все что угодно, если оно вам нужно. Обычно это сборная строка из нескольких параметров, но ее может вообще не быть, если она вам не нужна

Вот в целом и вся логика.

Алгоритм:

1. Пользователь заходит на сайт
2. Вынимаем сразу у него куки/ключи/токены/что-то еще, что может говорить о его авторизованности
3. Проверяем их на валидность и работоспособность. Если они еще действуют - просто авторизуем пользователя. Конец
4. Предлагаем пользователю выбрать вариант авторизации
5. По выбранному варианту получаем источник авторизации (поле [type] в таблице источников авторизации), проводим попытку авторизации этим способом.
6. Если успешно - получаем [user_id] и авторизуем. Конец
7. Если успешно, но такого пользователя у нас еще нет, молча создаем его и авторизуем. Конец
8. Если не успешно - просим повторить вход с выбором варианта или восстановить пароль. Можно начислить штраф на вход, паузу или показать капчу для продолжения, полезно. Только не переборщите с защитой, вводить капчу каждый раз на каждый чих - это перебор.

Comment: Спасибо за труд. Буду пробовать.